# How do I print the contents of an ApacheSpark RDD in my terminal?

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark

This is my first time using Scala and ApacheSpark for a project. I'm trying to print the contents of an matrix when I run my code in the terminal, but nothing I try is working so far.

Instead I only get this printed:

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.MatrixEntry;@71870da7
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.CoordinateMatrix@1dcca8d3
```

I just using `println()` but when I use `collect()`, that doesn't give  a good result either.

Comment: Generally speaking you don't. If something is small enough to be printed you don't need RDD. And if it is a final result or small subset you can collect and print local objects.

Answer (score 1):

The default toString prints the name of a class followed by an address in memory.

```
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.MatrixEntry;@71870da7
```

You're going to want to find a way to iterate through your matrix and print each element.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @zero323 's comment ( aside would you like to put an answer out there?): given an RDD[SomeType]  you can call

```
 rdd.collect()
```

or

```
 rdd.take(k)
```

Then you can print out the results using normal toString() methods that depend on the type of the rdd contents.  So if `SomeType` were a `List[Double]`  then the

```
println(s"${rdd.collect().mkString(",")}")
```

would give you a single-line comma separated output of the results.

As @zero323 another consideration is:  "do you *really* want to print out the contents of your rdd?"   More likely you might only want a summary - such as

```
println(s"Number of entries in RDD is ${rdd.count()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `rdd` like this,

```
rdd.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0):

scala>val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4)).map(_*2)

To print the data within RDD

scala> rdd1.collect().foreach(println)

Output:
2
4
6
8